# require is not defined when I have it installed - node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get my azure web app to read the sqlite3 module I installed using `npm install sqlite3`

if I made a folder called `nodetest` and make a `index.js` file with the following code, it works no problem: (meaning `require('sqlite3');` doesn't cause an error)

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
require('sqlite3'); 
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on('lunch',()=> {
    
    console.log('yum ')
    
} )

eventEmitter.emit('lunch');
```

[image]

However, if I try to add the same code to my actual `itglue.js` file it says `itglue.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in the inspection tools window in chrome.
code:

```
const urlx = "https://api.itglue.com/passwords/1238619592";
// require('sqlite3');
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
fetch(urlx, {
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        // needed to base64 encode my key with ":x" at the end of the api key then I used that for the authorization header.
    "x-api-key": "INSERTKEYHERE"
    }
})
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {console.log(data);
    let text = "Company: " + JSON.stringify(data["data"]['attributes'].username);
    const output = document.querySelector('span.ms-font-mx');
    
    let db = new sqlite3.Database("sqlite/companies.db", (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
      });

        let pre = document.createElement('p');
        
        pre.innerHTML = text;
        pre.style.cssText += 'font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;'

        output.appendChild(pre);
        db.close();
    })
```

[image]

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `require()` in the browser. It works in node, because sqlite3 is a module meant for node, not the browser.

Comment: Is there anyway to communicate between node and the javascript/html I am running? Is there any way to read the a file from azure web app from html or javascript to use any data in there as a variable. My main goal is to get some data from my sqlite file into javascript or html as a variable I can use. If I need to convert this file let me know. It doesn't sound like javascript works with sqlite. I thought I needed node for javascript to work.. From your post you make it seem like node is some sort of stand alone server only thing that can read javascript files with extra features.